# Not able to click on element using Selenium .click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below is the HTML tag :

```
<div onscroll="return isc_Canvas_4.$lh()" style="position: absolute; left: 6px; top: 6px; width: 12px; height: 12px; z-index: 201854; overflow: hidden; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; cursor: pointer; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px none; display: inline-block;" class="fa fa-caret-down" eventproxy="isc_Canvas_4" id="isc_55">&nbsp;</div>
```

I want to click on this element using Selenium. I have tried with selenium element.click() but it is not working.

Can anyone suggest any other way ? May be through JS or JQuery in Selenium.

Comment: Can you please explain how you defined `element` that you want to click on? Also, I think you should provide more HTML code snippet other than the above. If you provide that, we will be able to help you  to locate element using xpath.

Comment: XPATH , Actions nothing is working here. I am able to locate the element and retrieve its property but not able to click on it @TDHM. I think JS or JQuery can help here

Comment: `div` aren't usually click-able. This is most likely the issue. What is supposed to happen when you click that `div`?

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with following where javascript is executed on element:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Based on my knowledge, I won't be able to help you until I get webpage of that element and I also didn't understand what will happen after clicking on that element with `div` tag. Obviously, the element is representing neither button nor link.

Comment: How to click on element using JQuery in Selenium?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I would try with something like this.

If the ID of the DIV is the same at every load:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("isc_55")).click();
```

Else if the text of the DIV is the only one present:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), '&nbsp;')]")).click();
```

Or maybe even:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='&nbsp;']")).click();
```

It would help a lot with some more html and maybe some code?